# Como usar vários models em uma view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo um cadastro de pessoa física e tenho os seguintes *models*:

- `Pessoa`
- `Fisica`
- `Juridica`

E no código da minha *view* possuo apenas a declaração de um *model*:

```
@model CodeFirst.Models.Fisica
```

O problema é que quando eu for realizar um cadastro dentro da minha *view*, será necessário que eu tenha acesso aos 3 *models* listados acima. Como faço para ter acesso a eles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esse é um dos motivos pelos quais um *view model* é utilizado, um *view model* é um *model* que deverá ser utilizado exclusivamente para encapsular dados que serão enviados para a *view*. Então ao invés de você enviar um *model* diretamente para a *view*, você o encapsula dentro de um *view model* junto com outros dados que você deseja que a *view* tenha acesso.

No seu caso, o que poderia ser feito é o seguinte, você criaria uma classe dentro da pasta `/Models` do seu projeto seguindo o padrão `[NomeDaViewOndeSeráUtilizada]ViewModel` e dentro dessa classe você criaria uma propriedade para cada um desses *models*. Veja um exemplo:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Fisica Fisica { get; set; }
    public Juridica Juridica { get; set; }
}
```

E a *action* que retornaria esse *view model* poderia ficar assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

    // Preencha as propriedades do objeto viewModel como desejar
    // e o retorne para a view

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Conheço mais o WebForms e tinha está duvida também. Poderia dizer que outra maneira seria usando partialView?

Comment: @Marconi sim, uma outra maneira poderia ser utilizando uma *partial view*, mas a situação teria que ser analisada mais a fundo, isso porque uma *partial view* é geralmente utilizada para evitar repetição de código, ou seja, uma *partial view* geralmente será utilizada em mais de um lugar na aplicação, e outro ponto que vale a pena notar é que ainda assim será preciso enviar um *model* para a *partial view* como um dos parâmetros para chama-la de dentro da sua *view* e esse model pode ser obtido através do *view model* da *view* ou instânciado manualmente de dentro do código da *view*.

Comment: Ok,Obrigado. Boa resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @Zignd, funcionou perfeitamente!